# How to stop current job and start new job use quartz.net in asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, quartz.net

I've made a crawler on a website it has to read a website and fetch some values from it website.I've made use quartz.net and Asp.net MVC. but what is my problem? in fact,My problem is that for example,he/she the first time start for scraping a `"Stackoverflow.com"` about 5 hours and then he/she is decided stop `"stackoverflow.com"` and start a scrap new website.So,How can i do it?

[image]

```
   [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(string keyword, string url)
    {
        IScheduler scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.GetDefaultScheduler();

        scheduler.Start();
        IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<ScrapJob>()
            .WithIdentity("MyScrapJob")
            .UsingJobData("url", url)
            .UsingJobData("keyword", keyword)
            .Build();

        ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create().WithDailyTimeIntervalSchedule(
            s => s.WithIntervalInSeconds(20).OnEveryDay().StartingDailyAt(TimeOfDay.HourAndMinuteOfDay(0, 0))
            ).Build();
        scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);

        return View(db.Scraps.ToList());
    }
```

---

```
 public List<ScrapJob> Scraping(string url, string keyword)
    {
        int count = 0;
        List<ScrapJob> scraps = new List<ScrapJob>();
        ScrapJob scrap = null;
        HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
        try
        {
            var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            request.Method = "GET";

            using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            {

                using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    doc.Load(stream, Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8"));
                    foreach (HtmlNode node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//text()"))
                    {
                        if (node.InnerText.ToString().Contains(keyword))
                        {
                            count++;
                            scrap = new ScrapJob { Keyword = keyword, DateTime = System.DateTime.Now.ToString(), Count = count, Url = url };
                        }

                    }

                }
            }
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        //  scraps.Add(scrap);
        var isExist = db.Scraps.Where(s => s.Keyword == keyword && s.Count == scrap.Count).Max(s => (int?)s.Id) ?? 0;
        if (isExist == 0)
        {
            db.Scraps.Add(scrap);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }



        return scraps;
    }

    public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        //ScrapJob scraps = null;
        using (var scrap = new ScrapJob())
        {
            JobKey key = context.JobDetail.Key;
            JobDataMap dataMap = context.JobDetail.JobDataMap;
            string url = dataMap.GetString("url");
            string keyword = dataMap.GetString("keyword");
            scrap.Scraping(url, keyword);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you picked QUARTZ, but here is something that I think will help you.

This is a code sample that interrupt and delete job by unique identifier

```
public void DeleteJob(JobKey jobKey)
{
    var scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.GetDefaultScheduler();

    var executingJobs = scheduler.GetCurrentlyExecutingJobs();

    if (executingJobs.Any(x => x.JobDetail.Key.Equals(jobKey)))
    {
        scheduler.Interrupt(jobKey);
    }

    scheduler.DeleteJob(jobKey);
}
```

But I believe you need to define what behavior you expect, because it can be a bit more complex for example:

1. If you like to just pause the job and resume it after finish with the other website /persist some state and progress/ or just log the progress
2. If you want them to run in parallel and process multiple sites simultaneously. (You just need to give different names instead of the hardcoded   .WithIdentity("MyScrapJob") )
3. Also with scheduler.GetCurrentlyExecutingJobs() you can get the currently executing jobs, show them to the user and let him decide what to do.

Also looking at your action method I'm not sure whether this is the behavior you expect of that trigger. Also what bothers me is db.Scraps.ToList() you will materialize the whole table you can consider adding pagination as well in your case is not necessary because you will only show count but its mandatory if you have a lot of records in the grid.

About the scraping method 
Instead of

```
var isExist = db.Scraps.Where(s => s.Keyword == keyword && s.Count == scrap.Count).Max(s => (int?)s.Id) ?? 0;
```

you can use .Any

```
var exists = db.Scraps.Any(s => s.Keyword == keyword && s.Count == scrap.Count);
```

this will return boolean and you can check if(!exists)

You can check https://github.com/AngleSharp/AngleSharp it's high performance web parsing library. Super easy to use as well.

I see possibility of duplicated records by keyword if you check them by keyword and count - not sure whether you want this or just want to update the existing record with it's counter

Good luck! I hope this answer helps you :)

Comment: I've got this error when I want to delete job Quartz.UnableToInterruptJobException: can not be interrupted, since it does not implement Quartz.IInterruptableJob'